# Bittorrent magnitudes slower in 11.04 than in 10.10

Tags: networking, bittorrent

I'm running into a very strange issue related to bittorrent. Back in Maverick, I could download at about 2mbps per torrent. Now, i'll be lucky to get to 100kbps. Not only that, but any other network access slows to a crawl as soon as I start downloading something.

At first I thought it might be my router that was being overwhelmed with all the connections, but I checked my settings and saw that I had already set the global connections limit to 200, and a per torrent setting of 50. I've been able to have a much higher limit in the past, so that shouldn't be it.

Any ideas on how to troubleshoot this?

EDIT: To add to the mystery, I'm now using another computer with Natty on. I'm using the same torrents with the same bittorrent client and the same settings, and now it's working beautifully.

Answer (score 1):

Diagnosing slow torrent speed is not easy as there are a lot of moving variables involved.

There is a rather lengthy [BitTorrent optimization and troubleshooting guide](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1259923)
 on the Ubuntu forums.

You could also visit the forums for [Deluge](http://forum.deluge-torrent.org/) and [Transmission](https://forum.transmissionbt.com/).

Comment: I first noticed the problem when I was torrenting, but since then I've noticed the same kind of problems with regular http downloads. As such, I'm thinking it's a regression somewhere in the networking stack, rather than a problem with my torrent settings.

Comment: I thought that might be the case, therefore this question is not really valid.

Comment: @Tommy, modify your question to explain all the networking issues you are facing.